# Edit and Continue with TypeScript?

Tags: typescript

Is there any effort to support edit and continue with TypeScript? Everytime I want to change code while debugging I need to stop ad restart the entire debugging process...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the best answer to this question is "its up to the browser, and none of them do it well. Chrome does it the best, but for large complex js files it doesnt really work. Edge and IE dont even attempt it"

Comment: how do you do that in chrome/chromium?

Answer (score 3):

If you set your TypeScript files to "Compile on save" you won't need to re-build your project to get the changes.

This means you can edit your file, save it (give it time to update) then force refresh your browser.

Comment: You might need [Web Essentials 2012](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/07d54d12-7133-4e15-becb-6f451ea3bea6) for this.

Comment: Compile on save is available in the TypeScript Visual Studio 2012 extension. `TOOLS > Options > Text Editor > TypeScript > Project > Compile on Save`.

Comment: Compile on Save in VS2012 is broken, badly. Use Web Essentials version 2.9

Comment: Just bear in mind that TypeScript support is removed from Web Essentials - so you would be stuck on v2.9 forever if you do this.